# Python inspect module: keyword only args

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments, signature

The phrase "keyword only args" in Python is a bit ambiguous - usually I take it to mean args passed in to a `**kwarg` parameter.  However, the `inspect` module seems to make a distinction between `**kwarg` and something called "keyword only arguments".

From [**the docs**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec):

> **inspect.getfullargspec(func)**
>
> Get the names and default values of a Python function’s arguments. A
>   named tuple is returned:
>
> `FullArgSpec(args, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonlyargs, kwonlydefaults,
>             annotations)`
>
> `args` is a list of the argument names. `varargs` and `varkw` are the names
>   of the `*` and `**` arguments or `None`. defaults is an n-tuple of the
>   default values of the last n arguments, or None if there are no
>   default arguments. `kwonlyargs` is a list of keyword-only argument
>   names. `kwonlydefaults` is a dictionary mapping names from `kwonlyargs` to
>   defaults. `annotations` is a dictionary mapping argument names to
>   annotations.

So the inspect module has something called `kwonlyargs` and `kwonlydefaults`.  What does this mean in an actual function signature?  If you have a function signature that accept a `**kwarg` argument, you can't really know the *names* of the keyword arguments until runtime, because the caller can basically just pass any arbitrary dictionary.  So, what meaning does `kwonlyargs` have in the context of a *function signature* - which is what the `inspect.getfullargspec` provides.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR**:  Keyword-only arguments are not the same as normal keyword arguments.

---

Keyword-only arguments are arguments that come after `*args` and before `**kwargs` in a function call.  As an example, consider this generic function header:

```
def func(arg, *args, kwonly, **kwargs):
```

In the above, `kwonly` takes a keyword-only argument.  This means that you must supply its name when giving it a value.  In other words, you must explicitly write:

```
func(..., kwonly=value, ...)
```

instead of just passing a value:

```
func(..., value, ...)
```

---

To explain better, consider this sample call of the function given above:

```
func(1, 2, kwonly=3, kw=4)
```

When Python interprets this call, it will:

- Assign `arg` to `1` because its position in the function signature matches the position of `1` in the call.
- Place `2` in `*args` because `*args` collects any extra positional arguments and `2` is extra.
- Assign `kwonly` to `3` because we have (as is necessary) explicitly told it to.  Note that if we had done this instead:

  ```
  func(1, 2, 3, kw=4)
  ```

  `3` would also be placed in `*args` and a `TypeError` would be raised for not supplying an argument to `kwonly` (since we did not give it a default value in this case).
- Place `kw=4` in `**kwargs` because it is an extra keyword argument, which are collected by `**kwargs`.

Below is a demonstration of what I said above:

```
>>> def func(arg, *args, kwonly, **kwargs):
...     print('arg:', arg)
...     print('args:', args)
...     print('kwonly:', kwonly)
...     print('kwargs:', kwargs)
...
>>> func(1, 2, kwonly=3, kw=4)
arg: 1
args: (2,)
kwonly: 3
kwargs: {'kw': 4}
>>>
>>> func(1, 2, 3, kw=4)  # Should have written: 'kwonly=3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'kwonly'
>>>
```

Basically, you can look at keyword-only arguments as keyword arguments where you must supply the name of the parameter when giving them a value.  A positional value will not suffice, as with normal keyword arguments.

```
>>> def func(kw=None):
...     print('kw:', kw)
...
>>> func(kw=1)
kw: 1
>>> func(1)  # Do not need the name in this case.
kw: 1
>>>
>>> def func(*, kwonly=None):
...     print('kwonly:', kwonly)
...
>>> func(kwonly=1)
kwonly: 1
>>> func(1)  # Always need the name with keyword-only arguments.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
>>>
```

---

Finally, I know that some people are thinking "Why have keyword-only arguments anyways?"  The answer is simply that they make things more readable in some cases (especially with functions that take a variable number of arguments).

As an example, consider the built-in `max` function and its keyword-only `key` argument.  What is more readable to you?  Doing something like this:

```
max(lambda x: -x, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

and having people *remember* that the first argument to `max` is always the [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) or doing this:

```
max(arg1, arg2, arg3, key=lambda x: -x)
```

and making it clear to everyone that `lambda x: -x` is your key function.  Plus, making `key` a keyword-only argument allows you to simply omit the key function if you do not need one:

```
max(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

instead of doing:

```
max(None, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

---

For more information, you can check out these sources:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls
- https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter